# What does the "£" symbol mean for the following equation?

Tags: computer-science

In reference to Hamming Code:
**(n + 1) x 2^m *£* 2^n**
(2^m is "2 to the power m")

In context:

a code with words consisting of m data bits and r check bits

Each valid code word has n bits, and an error could occur in any of these n positions. Thus, each valid code word has n illegal code words at a distance of 1. Therefore, if we are concerned with each legal code word and each invalid code word consisting of one error, we have n + 1 bit patterns associated with each code word (1 legal word and n illegal words). Since each code word consists of n bits, where n = m + r, there are 2^n total bit patterns possible. This results in the following inequality:
**(n + 1) x 2^m £ 2^n**
where n + 1 is the number of bit patterns per code word, 2^m is the number of legal code words, and 2^n is the total number of bit patterns possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: british pound${}{}$

Comment: I'm guessing it's a rendering error? It's probably meant to be $\leq$.

Comment: By google book search, the same text (up to a change of "Because" to "Since") appear in page 109 of Linda Null and Julia Lobur's book "The Essentials of Computer Organization and Architecture". In that book, it is $\le$ instead of "£".

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense now.